# lanterna terminal input keeps repeating

Tags: java, input, while-loop, terminal, lanterna

I 'm making a simple java text-based hangman with lanterna (mainly becouse of clearscreen and user input in a console).

I have a problem with my user input: Once I typed in my input and run it trough my code, it keeps using that same input every time again, I can't insert another input anymore.

here's my code:

```
while (hidenWord.equals(word) == false) {
        //start of basic visual setup
        terminal.moveCursor(0,0);
        cursorPlace[0] = 0;cursorPlace[1] = 0;
        normalSetup(hidenWord, kansen, choose[categorie]);
        terminal.moveCursor(12, cursorPlace[1] - 3);
        //end of basic visual setup
        while (bool == false) {
            Thread.sleep(5);
            Key key = terminal.readInput();
            try {
                if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.NormalKey) {
                    guess = (key).toString().substring(key.toString().lastIndexOf(' '));
                    terminal.putCharacter(key.getCharacter());
                }
            } catch (Exception err) {
            }
            try {
                if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.Backspace) {
                    terminal.clearScreen();
                    terminal.moveCursor(0, 0);
                    cursorPlace[0] = 0;
                    cursorPlace[1] = 0;
                    normalSetup(hidenWord, kansen, choose[categorie]);
                    terminal.moveCursor(12, cursorPlace[1] - 3);
                }
            } catch (Exception err) {
            }
            try {
                if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.Enter && guess != null) {
                    bool = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception err) {
            }
        }
        if(word.contains(guess)){
            guesses.add(guess);
            hidenWord = addHidden(guess, word);
        }else{
            kansen --;
            miss.add(guess);
        }
        //end of other visual objects
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: This should be broken into more functions to improve read ability, then you can post only the relavent code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> while (hidenWord.equals(word) == false) {
>     // ...
>
>     while (bool == false) {
>         // ...
>
>         try {
>             if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.Enter && guess != null) {
>                 bool = true;
>             }
> ```

You set `bool` to true the first time you see an "Enter",
and afterwards you never reset it back to `false`.
As such, in the next iteration of the outer `while` loop,
`bool` is `true`, so the inner `while` loop is not entered again.

It would be simpler and better without using `bool` at all:

```
    while (true) {
        // ...

        try {
            if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.Enter && guess != null) {
                break;
            }
```